# DC/DC converter pi filter for switching frequency filtering

Tags: dc-dc-converter, filter, noise, passive-filter

I am using a DC/DC converter referenced as [ECLB75W-24D12](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/75/Datasheet_ECLB75W-2997961.pdf) for a product I am designing.

The problem I have is that the switching frequency of 330 kHz is too important on the input and won't pass conductive emission tests for certifications.
I tried to follow its [application note P14](https://www.cincon.com/productdownload/ECLB75W-series-application-note.pdf), where we can find a pi filter at the input. The problem is that even with such a filter I still see the noise at 330 kHz.

As I can't modify what is already on my PCB I tried to add an external pi filter with a lower cut-off frequency, as follows:

[image]

This should theoretically give a gain of -103 dB at 330 kHz:

[image]

Unfortunately, in practice, the noise is filtered a bit but still too important on the oscilloscope. The frequency detected as 111 kHz is wrong; if you check the period the noise is at 330 kHz (around 3 µs). In yellow is the input of the filter, and the blue is the output:

[image]

Assembling of the external pi filter for that test is a bit ugly but I don't think it matters really for the 330 kHz noise not being filtered:

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated to filter out that noise.

Comment: 1) Your probing technique is incorrect. The ground clip may pickup some noise and lead to false measurements. Note that you are not taking a differential measurement, 2) Although the simulation shows a total suppression at 330 kHz, things may change in real world as the components may show different properties at those frequencies. 3) What matters is the results of proper EMI measurement, not the peak-to-peak you are trying to measure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rohat. 
1) I will try with a spring to see if there is a difference to reduce the ground loop.
2) That is true, I will check if I can find any information on the impedance/frequency comportment of the components I am using.
3) Could you give more information regarding proper EMI measurement and how it is done please ?

Comment: You may want to look at the answer I gave [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651515/input-filter-transfer-function-derivation/651522#651522) regarding the TF of the EMI filter. Please also understand than trying to simulate a high-frequency circuit without accounting for its parasitics is almost useless. Try to insert the ESR and ESL of the cap, as well as the resonant network around the inductor and keep the shortest-possible connections in your breadboard.

Comment: Actually it's even worse than that: the period of the ringing is around 5MHz. Welcome to common mode noise! You will find the same signal is present on the ground itself (yes, probe the same point the ground lead is clipped to). This means ground is moving with respect to the scope. Add filtering to ground as well (usually with a common mode choke). Where else this current is flowing, depends on how the overall system is connected.