# Power factor EMC filter analysis

Tags: emc, power-factor-correction

As an embedded system engineer, I must admit that my knowledge in electronics is not particularly strong. Therefore, I am seeking assistance to clarify the purpose of certain elements in the provided design image.
Specifically, I would appreciate guidance on understanding the role and selection criteria for the following components:
C3, NTC1, C5, R1, R2 and C8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to detail all the selection process for these elements but let me try to summarize some of the key points:

\$C_3\$: this capacitor must be of X2 type considering its direct connection to the grid. It works in conjunction with the leakage inductance of the common-mode (CM) inductor \$L_1\$. It is used to filter the differential mode (DM) current generated by the front-end PFC stage. Determining its value is beyond the scope of this short answer but I gave some evidence in a previous [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651515/input-filter-transfer-function-derivation/651522#651522). Keep in mind that too high an input cap seriously degrades the *displacement* factor so you need to find a good balance between efficient filtering and good overall power factor (PF). As a final note, you must provide a discharge path to this capacitor when the user unplugs the cord so that no lethal voltage (below 50 V I think) is present at the plug prongs after 1 s - if I remember the spec well.

\$NTC\$: this component is there to limit the cold-start *in-rush* current. It happens because the output capacitor \$C_8\$ is discharged and offers a short-circuit to the grid at power up. The current is limited by the grid impedance, all the resistive paths from the power plug like the cord, the PCB traces, the rectifier resistance, the inductors (power and filter) etc. Not only this current can trip the breaker but it can bring *fatigue* to the components affected during this sequence. Furthermore, the power inductor saturates and you want to avoid that hence the *by-pass* diode \$D_2\$ which routes the current in a separate path. \$D_2\$ becomes silent once the PFC delivers its rated dc voltage. So the thermistor value is determined based on the specification of the end customer like what max surge current is tolerated when you plug the power supply for instance. Based on this value, you can determine the NTC value. Please note that in high-power converters - typically like the interleaved version you've shown - this NTC is short-circuited (by a relay or transistors) after the start-up sequence is over as its presence affects the efficiency figure.

\$C_5\$: in theory, you don't need this capacitor. However, practically-speaking, it helps a lot on the DM noise but it tends to degrade the cross-over distortion around the input 0-V area. I don't think there is a real formula for determining its value but I have seen values ranging from 0.47 µF to a few µF for high-power PFCs. You should find guidance in semi vendors PFC application notes ([onsemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/HBD853-D.PDF), [ST](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiVteHmgeT_AhVHSKQEHRWFBykQFnoECBMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fapplication_note%2Fcd00004002-l6561-enhanced-transition-mode-power-factor-corrector-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw35Gdwpc9oFlyo3ALvgWb7K&opi=89978449), [Infineon](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiVteHmgeT_AhVHSKQEHRWFBykQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infineon.com%2Fdgdl%2FInfineonApplicationNote_PFCCCMBoostConverterDesignGuide-AN-v02_00-EN.pdf%3FfileId%3D5546d4624a56eed8014a62c75a923b05&usg=AOvVaw0pZLpEfpIazixWn7sPs1kG&opi=89978449) etc.)

\$C_8\$: this is the bulk capacitor. It is determined based on the acceptable low-frequency ripple (at twice the line frequency, 100 or 120 Hz) you can accept - e.g. how low the output voltage drops in normal operation - and also the transient response to a load step. But if there is an expression for determining the needed capacitance, in the end, as often the case, the rms current and rated voltage of available parts will guide you for selecting a final value. Keep in mind that this bulk capacitor sees a part of the low-frequency ripple but also a significant part of the high-frequency pulses supplied to the downstream converter. You can use equations to determine these values and then use simulation to confirm. I have a ready-made PFC stage in my free SIMPLIS [templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf).

For an introductory seminar on PFCs, I recommend you look at the [one](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20PFC.pdf) I recently posted on my [page](http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm). There is a lot of information in a condensed form.

Comment: Is it just me or is C1 and C2 in the wrong place? The common mode inductance doesn't have a C/2 part of the filter to work with, at least in the correct direction. Shouldn't they be on the right hand side of the CM inductor?

Comment: On the paper, if you want to reduce the injected CM noise generated by the power supply, they have to appear in the right side of the CM choke. This [document](https://www.us.lambda.tdk.com/resources/blogs/201905.html) from TDK Lambda seems to indicate that both connections (right and left sides) are possible.